# Bessel's inequality

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^2(-\pi, \pi)$, $S_{N,f} = \sum_{|k| \leq N, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}}\langle {e_k,f} \rangle  e_{k}(x)$ where $e_k(x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{2ikx}$. Is it true $\|S_{N,f}\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{L^2}$?

I need a hint on where to start on this problem.

Comment: What is $f_k$ ?

Comment: I presume that the coefficients in $S_{N,f}$ should be $\langle e_k,f\rangle$ instead of $\langle e_k,f_k\rangle$.

Comment: it's correct, it's a typo. @FrankLu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\{e_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. It follows that
$$\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2=\sum_{|k|\leq N}|\langle e_k,f\rangle|^2.$$
Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}0&\leq\|f-S_{N,f}\|_2^2=\langle f-S_{N,f},f-S_{N,f}\rangle\\
&=\langle f,f\rangle-\langle S_{N,f},f\rangle-\langle f,S_{N,f}\rangle+\langle S_{N,f},S_{N,f}\rangle\\
&=\langle f,f\rangle-\overline{\langle f,S_{N,f}\rangle}-\langle f,S_{N,f}\rangle+\langle S_{N,f},S_{N,f}\rangle\\
&=\|f\|_2^2+\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2-2\text{Re}\langle f,S_{N,f}\rangle\\
&=\|f\|_2^2+\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2-2\text{Re}\sum_{|k|\leq N}\langle e_k,f\rangle\overline{\langle e_k,f\rangle}\\
&=\|f\|_2^2+\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2-2\text{Re}\sum_{|k|\leq N}|\langle e_k,f\rangle|^2\\
&=\|f\|_2^2+\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2-2\sum_{|k|\leq N}|\langle e_k,f\rangle|^2\\
&=\|f\|_2^2-\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: where does this equality come from $\|f-S_{N,f}\|_2^2=\|f\|_2^2+\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2-2\sum_{|k|\leq N}|\langle e_k,f\rangle|^2$?

Comment: I've included more details

Comment: May I ask how you came up with the idea to start from $0\leq\|f-S_{N,f}\|_2^2$?

Comment: The intuition mainly came from the fact that $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal set and the Pythagorean theorem.From this we can get the desired expression of $\|S_{N,f}\|_2^2$, which is closely related to $\langle f,S_{N,f}\rangle$. Then it is natual to think of $\|f-S_{N,f}\|_2^2$.